# Assign Approvers based on folder?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, folder, approval-process, approval

I'm working on implementing a workflow which will start automatically on change/creation (which is working). The issue is that there are a few folders which need cross-department approval. Is there a way for a workflow to check which folder in the document library the file is in before assigning Approval tasks?

Ex) In the below structure, I would need File A to be approved by Ann, Bob, and Chris. Meanwhile, File B would need to be approved by Dan, Eric, and Fred.

```
Dept 1
|
|- Folder 1
|  |
|  |- File A
|
|- Folder 2
|  |
|  |- File B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if current item relative URL is contain Folder name then assign task to related user.

You can refer below screenshot as example
[image]

To check current document inside Folder(e.g. Folder4) or not. please follow below step that mention on screenshot.

1. Get Current Document Server Relative URL. `sites/tempsite/libraryname/Folder4/document.docx`
2. Then find index of Folder Name. `Folder4`
3. Check if Index is greater then -1 then current document is inside folder

**Note: -** Makes sure that folder name and List name or Folder name and Site name are not same.